# vim: matter is exec or normal command?

Tags: vim

source code:

```
function! myfunc()
    execute "normal! i\<c-r>=12+34\<cr>"
endfunc

inoremap <silent><Tab> <C-R>=myfunc()<CR>
```

i have the above code in my .vimrc, which means if i'm typing `<tab>` in insert mode and then it will append 46. for example, open a new file, type "hello"(no double quote here) and then press `<tab>` key, the result should be "hello46". While it doesn't. so why?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the expression register. It seems like what you want is for myfunc to just return 12+34

Comment: If you want to put something at the cursor, use <expr> as in inoremap <expr><Tab> Myfunc()  also your function must be capitalized at the start. i'm trying to figure out why it won't overwrite tab now, if you replace tab with 'a' you get what you want

Comment: yes, for sure. Actually, what i am wanting to do is that typing an <tab> to insert an string to current position. i just simplified it to above aspect. Thanks for you reply!!!

Comment: And an good news is if we move the cursor to the last position again. and then pressing <tab>, it works! So, seems like i have to do these 2 times to get what i desired!! Weird!!!

Comment: what i wanna do is pressing <tab> key, and then insert the current place an variable. for instance: let s:varialbe = "something", after pressing <tab>, inserting the s:varialbe to current position. I am doing an code complete stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do simple math:

```
execute "normal! i" . (12 + 34)
```

But you could use this form:

```
inoremap <expr> <tab> 12 + 34
```

***edit***

Your errors:

1. Function names must begin with a capital.
2. `<C-r>=` is used to insert the result of an expression but your function doesn't return anything: it executes a normal mode command instead.

This version of your snippet works. The function returns something that you can insert with `<C-r>=` in your mapping:

```
function! MyFunc()
  let myvar = "foo"
  return myvar
endfunc

inoremap <silent> <Tab> <C-r>=MyFunc()<CR>
```